# OpenCV imshow shows very grainy image. How to fix this?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I have a CT image that look like this when I plot it using dicom:
[image: Image in pydicom]

But when I try to use opencv, it appears like this:

[image: Image in OpenCV]

Array is dtype=uint16. My code to visualize in OpenCV:

```
img = np.array(ct_img * 255, dtype = np.uint16)
cv2.imshow('Annotated',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Please help fix the image. Image quality gets worse when I convert to np.uint32 or np.unint8

Comment: Please show more of your code; where do you get `ct_img` in the first place? Why are you multiplying it by 255?

Comment: Use skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity() to stretch linearly to full dynamic range. Use input="image" and output=(0,255)

Answer (score 0):

`exposure.equalize_adapthist()` solved the issue.

Comment: You'd better solve the scaling issue. Histogram modification distorts the scale of grays non linearly.

Comment: Please explain a bit more what you were doing and what the result looks like.